# Testing a component that uses apollo-link-state with Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a component that switches the langauge in my application. If the current language is "en" it displays a link with the text "Francais" and if the current language is "fr" it displays a link with the text "English".

When clicked it toggles the language between "en" and "fr". I am trying to write a test for that behaviour.

The current language is stored in the Apollo client cache using apollo-link-state.

I wrote the following test, which I think should pass, but does not.

```
describe('when clicked', async () => {
  it('changes the language displayed to English', async () => {
    const englishClient = testClient({ language: 'en' })
    const wrapper = mount(
      <ApolloProvider client={englishClient}>
        <LanguageSwitcher />
      </ApolloProvider>,
    )
    wrapper.find('a').simulate('click')
    wrapper.update()

    expect(wrapper.text()).toMatch(/English/)
  })
})
```

I would like to understand why this test fails, and how to get it to pass.

If there is a better approach/best practice for testing this sort of thing, I'd love to know.

You can see the code and run the tests in a Codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/kmnwy1z8v

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?